# Java alternative for curl -T

Tags: java, http, post, curl

i must send one text string using java to a IP web cam, before it take picture. So after I read the camera user manual and searched in google, the only thing i found was using cURL. I install it and its run fine, and everything is okay, the text from the file appear in the video streaming. The command is this
**curl -T test.xml http://admin:pass@192.168.0.1/Video/inputs/channels/2/overlays/text/2**
and the content of test.xml is:

```
<TextOverlay xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver10/XMLSchema" version="1.0"> 
<id>2</id>
<enabled>true</enabled>
<posX>5</posX>
<posY>5</posY>
<message>Text here </message>
</TextOverlay>
```

So I want to send this content using Java, I already tried using post and java.net but I get an error "Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL"

Here is my code:

```
 System.out.println("Starting......");
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.1/Video/inputs/channels/2/overlays/text/2/");
String data = "<TextOverlay xmlns=\"http://www.hikvision.com/ver10/XMLSchema\" version=\"1.0\">\n"
    + "<id>2</id>\n"
    + "<enabled>true</enabled>\n"
    + "<posX>5</posX>\n"
    + "<posY>5</posY>\n"
    + "<message>Text here</message>\n"
    + "</TextOverlay>";
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = prepareConn(url, null, "admin", "pass");
httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpConnection.setRequestProperty ( "Content-Type", "text/xml" );
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(data);
out.flush();
out.close();
System.out.println("Printing......");
System.out.println(httpConnection.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(httpConnection.getResponseMessage());
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream());
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
char[] cbuf = new char[2048];
int num;

while(-1 != (num = reader.read(cbuf)))
{
  buf.append(cbuf, 0, num);
}

String result = buf.toString();
System.out.println("\nResponse received from server after POST" + result);  
}


static  private HttpURLConnection prepareConn(final URL url, Properties request_props, String username, String password) throws Error, IOException
{
System.out.println("Authorization......");
if (!url.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("http"))
  throw new Error(url.toString() + " is not HTTP!");

final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(300);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

final Properties DEFAULT_REQUEST_PROPS = new Properties();
DEFAULT_REQUEST_PROPS.setProperty("charset", "utf-8");

final Properties props = new Properties(DEFAULT_REQUEST_PROPS);
if (request_props != null)
  for (final String name : request_props.stringPropertyNames())
    props.setProperty(name, request_props.getProperty(name));

for (final String name : props.stringPropertyNames())
  conn.setRequestProperty(name, props.getProperty(name));
if(null != username && null != password)
  conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + new BASE64Encoder().encode((username+":"+password).getBytes()));
return conn;
}
```

Hope someone can help :)
All the best !

Answer (score 2):

I just use wrong `RequestMethod`, after deep research I found that i must use PUT not POST request. Now just change `setRequestMethod("POST")` to `setRequestMethod("PUT")` and works like a charm.

Comment: Hey thanks -- I'm doing the exact same thing as you and this came in very useful! Cheers from another Hikvision user!